Tone js Grain Player Echo with Playback Rate
I am having an issue with tone.js (latest version) and the grain player to control playback rate and pitch individually. Also I am using stereo wav files which is just a recording. The issue is that when adjusting the playback rate I am getting an echo. I tried playing around with the overlap and grain size settings but nothing is working. I created a simple example and was able to reproduce it.
I tried it with a stereo and mono wav file, it didn't make a difference.
<button id="playPauseBtn">Play</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tone"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        let player = new Tone.GrainPlayer("myStereoWaveFile.wav").toDestination();

        player.playbackRate = 0.5;
        player.sync().start(0);
        
        $("#playPauseBtn").on("click", function() {
            let $target = $(this);
            
            if ($target.text() === "Play") {
                $target.text("Pause");
                Tone.getTransport().start();
            }
            else {
                $target.text("Play");
                Tone.getTransport().pause();
            }
        });
    });
</script>

Sample stereo wav file for testing
